# Draw SVG wheel and add text to outerparts

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to draw a wheel using svg that is created by Javascript. The wheel segments are based on the size of the array.

Everything draws fine, but the text (on the outer parts of the wheel) don't seem to be rendered along the text path.

This is the part of my code that should be creating a link to the path elements for the text to follow however nothing appears when the page is generated.

```
var arcOutTextPath = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'textPath');

arcOutTextPath.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, "xlink:href", "#" + career[i]);
arcOutTextPath.textContent = career[i].replace("_", " ");

arcOutText.appendChild(arcOutTextPath);
```

[I've also added the full code on CodePen](http://codepen.io/tomhumphrey/pen/GqWRoW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xlinkNS has the wrong protocol: https than http. You want this:

```
var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
```

Comment: Brilliant - Thank you, one character change and they all turned up!